# writing XPATH Expression

Tags: c#, xpath

Hello I have a xml file from whihc i would like ot have a part of it. SO, this is my xml file:

```
           <Item Text="Reports" Navigateurl ="Reports/Default.aspx">
  <Group>
    <Item Text="Customers" NavigateUrl="Reports/Customers/Default.aspx" Select="true">
      <Group>
        <Item Text="Customers" NavigateUrl="Reports/Customers/CustomerList.aspx" 
              Select="true"   />
        <Item Text="Customer Products" 
                    NavigateUrl="Reports/Customers/CustomersProducts.aspx" Select="true" />
        <Item Text="Customer Measurements" 
           NavigateUrl="Reports/Customers/CustomerLocationMeasurements.aspx" 
                Select="true"  />
        <Item Text="Customer Groups" NavigateUrl="Reports/Customers/CustomerGroups.aspx" />
        <Item Text="Customer Outages"  
             NavigateUrl="Reports/Customers/CustomerOutages.aspx" Select="true"/>
      </Group>
    </Item>
```

To select this part I used this expression:

```
        XmlDataSource XmlDataSource1 = new XmlDataSource();
        XmlDataSource1.DataFile = "~/Menu.xml";
        XmlDataSource1.XPath = "//Item[@Text ='Customers']/Group";
        XmlDataSource1.DataBind();
```

The result would be

```
     Group
       Customers
       CustomerProducts
       ..........
```

But i wanted only those for which select attribute is true. But i have not been able to figure how to do it. Can you please help me?

Comment: `//Item[@Text ='Customers'][@Select='true']` should do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct way:

```
XmlDataSource1.XPath = "//Item[@Text ='Customers']/Group/Item[@Select = 'true']";
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure i remember this correctly - but i think this is the way to do it.

```
XmlDataSource1.XPath = "//Item[@Text ='Customers']/Group[/Item/@Select='true']";
```

Comment: "//Item[@Text ='Customers']/Group/Item[@Select='true']";
This works........ Just a little bit modiifcation.... Thank you

Comment: Np.. And thank you for posting the correct way to do it :) I did not remember that

Answer (score 0):

Since XPATH is XPATH, i've worked out the example in php as i don't have a c# compiler handy on my mac atm.

The path statement `"//Item[@Text ='Customers'][@Select='true']"` results in:

```
Reports/Customers/Default.aspx
Reports/Customers/CustomerList.aspx
```

The example code:

```
<?php

$xml = <<<XML
<Item Text="Reports" Navigateurl ="Reports/Default.aspx">
    <Group>
        <Item Text="Customers" NavigateUrl="Reports/Customers/Default.aspx" Select="true">
            <Group>
                <Item Text="Customers" NavigateUrl="Reports/Customers/CustomerList.aspx" Select="true"   />
                <Item Text="Customer Products" NavigateUrl="Reports/Customers/CustomersProducts.aspx" Select="true" />
                <Item Text="Customer Measurements" NavigateUrl="Reports/Customers/CustomerLocationMeasurements.aspx" Select="true"  />
                <Item Text="Customer Groups" NavigateUrl="Reports/Customers/CustomerGroups.aspx" />
                <Item Text="Customer Outages" NavigateUrl="Reports/Customers/CustomerOutages.aspx" Select="true"/>
            </Group>
        </Item>
    </Group>
</Item>
XML;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$list = $xpath->query("//Item[@Text ='Customers'][@Select='true']");
foreach($list as $item)
{
    printf("%s\n", $item->getAttribute('NavigateUrl'));
}
```